# Omit unwanted interface methods with same names in typescript

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the typescript interface generated from compiler, and there are methods with same name (overloaded methods) but some I don't want (it will cause error in later in util.promisify. I can't comment out unwanted methods and later code work, but TS code may generated anytime). Can I get rid of some?

before:

```
export interface GreeterClient extends grpc.Client {
  sayHello(argument: _helloworld_HelloRequest, metadata: grpc.Metadata, options: grpc.CallOptions, callback: (error?: grpc.ServiceError, result?: _helloworld_HelloReply__Output) => void): grpc.ClientUnaryCall;
  sayHello(argument: _helloworld_HelloRequest, metadata: grpc.Metadata, callback: (error?: grpc.ServiceError, result?: _helloworld_HelloReply__Output) => void): grpc.ClientUnaryCall;
  sayHello(argument: _helloworld_HelloRequest, options: grpc.CallOptions, callback: (error?: grpc.ServiceError, result?: _helloworld_HelloReply__Output) => void): grpc.ClientUnaryCall;
  sayHello(argument: _helloworld_HelloRequest, callback: (error?: grpc.ServiceError, result?: _helloworld_HelloReply__Output) => void): grpc.ClientUnaryCall;
}
```

after:
before(the result I want):

```
export interface GreeterClient extends grpc.Client {
  sayHello(argument: _helloworld_HelloRequest, options: grpc.CallOptions, callback: (error?: grpc.ServiceError, result?: _helloworld_HelloReply__Output) => void): grpc.ClientUnaryCall;
}
```

Comment: *"...methods with same name..."* Just for what it's worth, the term is "overloaded methods."

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If A) there other methods generated by the compiler that use `GreeterClient` as a parameter type, and B) you create `GreeterClient` instances with your code that you'll pass into those methods as arguments, then no, you can't get rid of the overloads because whatever method is expecting an instance matching the compiler-created `GreeterClient` definition may well require one of the overloads you don't want.

But if your code never creates `GreeterClient` instances (it only *uses* them), or you never give `GreeterClient` instances you create to code that isn't yours, then you should be able to remove the overloads you don't want since your code won't use them.

Comment: I am sure I don't want some generated overloads. The mutiple definitions of method cause the bug in laster ts code. So I just want filter some. I just use GreeterClient as type, will not create instances from it, and others code won't need unnecessary code neither